# Kotlin Synthetic: Referencing views with the same ids in several layouts with dynamic inflating

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have two layouts: data_a.xml and data_b.xml. They are both made to display the same data, but laid out differently. Both layout have a `TextView` with the id `data_label`.

My custom view `DataView` allows to inflate data_a.xml or data_b.xml to render my data, depending on a `Styleable` having a `layout` attribute.

DataView.kt:

```
class DataView(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        var layoutResId = R.layout.data_a
        if (attrs != null) {
            val a = context?.theme?.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DataView, 0, 0)
            try {
                layoutResId = a!!.getResourceId(R.styleable.DataView_layout, layoutResId)
            } finally {
                a?.recycle()
            }
        }
        View.inflate(context, layoutResId, this)
        data_label.text = "Foobar" // this won't work if I choose data_b.xml as layout
    }
}
```

attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="DataView">
    <attr name="layout" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

And this is how I choose which layout to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    ...
    <com.duh.DataView
        android:id="@+id/data_view"
        app:layout="@layout/data_a"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Is there a way to use Kotlin Synthetic to do this?

Comment: If you have same ids on both layouts you can use only one of them in import. Syntetic anyway works the same way as finviewbyid. So if id the same - it find necessary view

Answer (score 6):

If you want to import different widgets with the same ID with Kotlin Synthetic, you can alias them in your imports:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.data_a.view.data_label as labelA
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.data_b.view.data_label as labelB
```

Then in your `DataView` you can assign your text to the `TextView` which is not null, depending on the layout you inflated:

```
(labelA ?: labelB)?.text = "Foobar"
```

Comment: I know about aliases for imports, but the fact that the targeted layout has to be named in `DataView` (import kotlinx...data_xxx...) is a problem. If later in the project I want to create a data_c.xml layout, I'll have to modify the `DataView` class where I shouldn't need.